# How to test a file attach with rspec in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I put a file upload tag in my view source:

```
<%= form_tag(confirm_path, method: :post, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'my_file' %>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
<% end %>
```

I want to test if user select a file and click submit button, then redirect to next page. Here is my spec source:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'MyTest', type: :feature do
  describe 'File test' do
    before do
      visit index_path
    end

    it 'If select a file, then go to next page' do
      attach_file 'my_file', my_real_file_path # I am sure this file exists
      click_button 'Submit'
      expect(page).to have_content('Confirm Page')
    end
  end
end
```

But after I run this spec test, it said:

```
Failure/Error: attach_file 'my_file', my_real_file_path
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find file field 'my_file'
```

Comment: Can you post your form that this is being submitted through? (i.e simple_form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually because the actual file field is being hidden and overlayed with a "button" or some JavaScript driven interface so it can be styled to look the same across multiple browsers.  If this is the case here you generally need to execute some JavaScript, using execute_script, to override whatever css is hiding the file field so it becomes visible on the screen and then call attach_file

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure your meaning. What is `execute_script`? I am not using css to hide the file field.

Comment: page.execute_script 'javascript to execute in the page'. Allows for executing JavaScript on the page.  If you're not hiding the file field then it's irrelevant and you should post the actual html of your form, since there's no reason for the element not to be found

Comment: Actually, where is your visit to the page with the field field on it?

Comment: Thanks. I use this to visit index page: `visit index_path`. The file tag is in my index page.

Comment: Use save_and_open_page and then post the actual html rather than your erb template

Comment: Thank you. I have added `save_and_open_page`, then how to post actual html in my spec source?

Comment: Just open the saved file in an editor and copy the generated source, or create a Gist with the html and paste a link